# instead it is calling for Array class add() its calling for ArrayCount class add()

Tags: java, testing

I would like to know the reason for fragile base class problem in java.

Here is the code and i cant find the reason for triggering child class method even if i have given instruction to trigger a method in parent class

in public class Array

```
public class Array {
    private ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void add(Object element)
    {
        a.add(element);
    }

    public void addAll(Object elements[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
            add(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

in ArrayCount class... this class is responsible for store the count of the list

```
public class ArrayCount extends Array {
    public int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void add(Object element)
    {
        super.add(element);
        ++count;
    }

    @Override
    public void addAll(Object elements[])
    {
        super.addAll(elements);
        count += elements.length;
    }
}
```

main class as follows

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayCount ac = new ArrayCount();
        Object [] objArray = new Object[7];
        objArray[0] = "xxx";
        objArray[1] = "xxx";
        objArray[2] = "xxx";
        objArray[3] = "xxx";
        objArray[4] = "xxx";
        objArray[5] = "xxx";
        objArray[6] = "xxx";

        ac.addAll(objArray);
        System.out.println("count is : " + ac.count);
        //COUNT IS 14 NOT 7
    }
}
```

Comment: you've declared it as an instance of ArrayCount, and initialized it as being an ArrayCount, so it's to be expected it behaves like an ArrayCount

Comment: ok.. but in ArrayCount addAll method i have called `super.addAll()` and in Array class addAll method it has called for `add()` method. the problem is instead it is calling for Array class `add()` its calling for ArrayCount class `add()` method from Array class `addAll()` method

Comment: "problem is instead it is calling for Array class add() its calling for ArrayCount class add()" => This is the core concept of OOP! Polymorphism! Method calls are _dynamically bound_. And - in fact - this is the reason why the base class is called _fragile_.

Comment: everything works as expected here.

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle that doesn't mean the rest of that method doesn't run

Comment: Rule of thumb here: **Don't call overridable methods inside your base class.**

Comment: created object for ArrayCount and called the method of same class. but inside Arraycount you are calling the base class method. So it will go to the base class.

Comment: problem is its not going to the base class. and the output of the value of the count variable is 14 not 7

Comment: Works fine, no problem here.

Comment: The count is 14 because both the `++count;` from `ArrayCount.add()` and the `count += elements.length;` from `ArrayCount.addAll()` are executed. The flow is as follows: `ArrayCount.addAll() -> Array.addAll() -> ArrayCount.add() -> Array.add()` where the parts that must surprise you is that the `add()` in `Array.addAll()` is effectively the one from `ArrayCount.add()`